# Why does a object parallel to my ToF sensor doesn't look parallel in the point cloud?

Tags: opencv, 3d, kinect, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I was comparing Kinect V2 with my own ToF sensor and I found a different place.

Below is a point cloud with RGB information produced by Kinect V2, which is placed in front of a object, and the object is placed between two walls. This means the two walls are parallel to Kinect V2's view line.

[image: Front View]

If I drag the point cloud, you can see the point cloud of two walls in the .ply file are parallel with each other and parallel with the Kinect' view line.

Look from top of the point cloud
[image: The Left Wall]
[image: The Right Wall]

However, if I use my own ToF sensor to catch the point cloud under same environment and same view(please ignore the difference of the object in the middle, it has been changed), the point cloud looks like this(color camera hasn't been implemented)
[image: My ToF Sensor]

The left wall(red circle area) somehow distorted like a "/"(The right wall cannot visualize due to my sensor's FOV)

I was confused by this phenomenon, I pretty sure Kinect V2 did some processes to fix this issue, but I cannot figure it out.

Can someone give me some clues about the scene I saw?

If there is any further information need to be provided, feel free to ask.

Comment: Since there are two parallel walls, there might be some multiple reflections of the signal (echos). Could it be an artefact due to such an echo that would be correctly handled by the Kinect V2 but not by your ToF camera ?

Comment: @AldurDisciple This doesn't only happen with two parallel walls, Whatever parallel to the ToF sensor's view line will appear like "/" or "\"(flat plane or straight line is more easy to observe). However, as the object getting closer to the middle of the sensor, this phenomenon slowly disappears.

Comment: You are using the DepthSense I assume, and using the SDK's own reprojection routines?

Comment: @D.J.Duff Yes, DepthSense it is, I used it to retrieve vertices data from the sensor, but I visualize the point cloud image with Point Cloud Library, by making out a .pcd file.

Answer (score 0):

TOF cameras suffer from many systematic errors from both sensor and illumination unit which result in inhomogeneus lighting for example.

I did a detailed study on this topic that can be find at this address:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05459.pdf

The error gets a lot worth on the border of your frame, as the active illumination has never:

1. same fov as camera
2. same power on center and border of the frame

For your case I think the problem is happening at the border where the measured distance gets extremely unlinear for the border pixels. Check figure 5 and 15 in the paper.

Possible solutions:

1. Try to remain between 1 and 3 meter distance.
2. Concentrate more on the central 2/3 of the frame.